# make selecInput list from data.frame

Tags: r, shiny

Is possible to make a list for a selectInput from reading a data.frame?

As I understand, one uses the options of a selectInput to subset a data.frame in the server.R, not the other way around.

I cannot make a premade list, as I won't know how many options there would be. So my app should:

**Read data.frame, get unique observations of campaign column and put them in a list, use that list in `selectInput`**

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse) 



shinyApp(

ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
              list(`East Coast` = c("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                   `West Coast` = c("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                   `Midwest` = c("MN", "WI", "IA"))
  ),
  textOutput("result")
),
    server = function(input, output) {


      fb <- reactive({ 

        fb_data <- read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ry6gfksljbpg1d6/curacao-fb-julago.csv?dl=1", skip = 0)

      })


      lst_campaigns <- unique(fb()$campaign)  

      lst_campaigns
    }
  )
```

Link for `selectInput` information:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `updateSelectInput` does that job.

In the example below, clicking the update button invokes reading your dropbox file and update the campaign list.
Note that I pass only the first ten campaigns to the choices, since 11-th entry causes error (perhaps there is an illegal character that shiny cannot handle).

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse) 

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                list(`East Coast` = c("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                     `West Coast` = c("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                     `Midwest` = c("MN", "WI", "IA"))),
    actionButton("update", "Update"),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    fb <- reactive({ 
      fb_data <- read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ry6gfksljbpg1d6/curacao-fb-julago.csv?dl=1", skip = 0)
      fb_data
    })

    observeEvent(input$update, {
      dat = fb()
      lst_campaigns <- unique(dat$campaign) 
      updateSelectInput(session, "state",
                        choices=head(lst_campaigns, 10), 
                        selected=lst_campaigns[1])  
    })
  }
)
```

`server` for automatic start.

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
    fb_data <- read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ry6gfksljbpg1d6/curacao-fb-julago.csv?dl=1", skip = 0)
    lst_campaigns <- unique(fb_data$campaign) 
    updateSelectInput(session, "state",
                      choices=head(lst_campaigns, 10), 
                      selected=lst_campaigns[1])  
}
```

Comment: Does it update it as soon as it reads the data (automatically)? It doesn't show error but selectInput doesn't reflect the campagins from data.

Comment: Now I did and it worked out! But I was wondering if its possible to make automatically? However, I could use some dummy campaign names as placeholders and make the user push the "Update" buttom. ty

Comment: Yes, you can make it automatic.  A tricky part is `reactive`, which works only within a reactive environment.  The button was just to create one.  To make an automatic (and one-shot) update, you can simply skip `reactive`.  See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using both `updateSelectInput` and `observe` functions as follows:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
           selectInput("species", "Select a specie:", choices = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    iris
  })

  observe({
    # Dont run unless a data have been imported 
    req(data())

    unique_obs <- levels(data()[, 'Species'])

    updateSelectInput(session = session, "species", choices = unique_obs)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```